# Using jade(pug) to create jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, pug

I would like to write a fast and easy to maintain html/jsp code, so I read about html processors and jade(pug), which seems to be ok for me.

But now I have a problem because I can't/don't know how to:

- create file with JSP extension using pug
- inject "`<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>`" from pug to my jsp file

Or maybe there is a different approach for this?

Ok I just solved my problem:

- for extension we need to use this

`pug index1.pug --extension jsp --pretty`

- We can just insert this to pug file

Comment: solution: pug index1.pug --extension jsp --pretty and we can just insert <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> and all will be ok

Answer (score 0):

*From an edit to the question:*

Ok I just solved my problem:

for extension we need to use this:

```
pug index1.pug --extension jsp --pretty
```

We can just insert this to pug file